# Unable to extract (US) Zipcode from doc file

Tags: asp.net, doc, zipcode

I am need to get the Zipcode from the Resume.doc file..
but not succceded,,,

Its working with static string , I mean it validates the static string but unable to parse the zipcode from doc file,,

I am sharing my code ...

```
   protected void zipcodeGetter()
    {
        var path = "C:\\Users\\Jatinder\\Desktop\\LUCENE\\Resume\\Jeffrey.doc";
        Document doc = new Document();
        string html = File.ReadAllText(path);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        const string MatchPhondePattern = @"^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$";
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchPhondePattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(html);
        // Report the number of matches found.
        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
        //Do something with the matches
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            //Do something with the matches
            string tempPhoneNumber = match.Value.ToString(); ;

        }
    }
```

can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Your code just won't work with that regular expression.

This problem is complicated and your best option is to use a service from a company that does this. They will have a robust system.

Here is a quote from [an article on regex and addresses](https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses):

> We get a lot of questions from programmers about parsing addresses. We see a lot of people trying to use regular expressions for street addresses, and as the address user experience experts, we cringe whenever another programmer falls prey to this trap. We hope that this information will save you some trouble, and if your searching is in vain, please feel free to ask us any questions you have about addresses. ... 
>   Should you use regular expressions to parse street addresses? The short answer is, "Probably not." Because of the wide variance in address content and formatting, addresses aren't "regular"—an indispensable factor in using regular expressions to process information.

---

Now, some notes and hints about your regular expressions.

I used RegExr to make an [example of the regular expression](http://regexr.com/3e43v) you used. As you can see, there are no highlighted regions, meaning your regular expression won't work.

If you just want to match five consecutive digits, the regular expression is: `[0-9]{5}`. Here is [an example](http://regexr.com/3e442).

You can't just use `^` and `$` because, for example, there might be a space or a period before or after the zip code and `^` and `$` in your code would mean you're looking for beginnings and ends of lines.

The problem with not having any other qualifiers, however, is you will match long numbers, too. In other words, with a string like `1234567890`, you will match `[0-9]{5}` because there are five consecutive digits in that string.

It's hard to qualify the regular expression with possible punctuation or spaces before or after the match, because what if the match is at the beginning or end of the line? It [will miss some](http://regexr.com/3e445).

Here is a regex that might be useful to you. It seems to work in a lot of cases. You can see the [example here](https://regex101.com/r/4e7XCb/1), with more explanation.

`(?<=\W|^)\d{5}(-?\d{4})?(?=\W|$)`

(Full disclosure: I work for SmartyStreets and we have [an API](https://smartystreets.com/features#extract) that does this. Check out the [API docs](https://smartystreets.com/docs/us-extract-api) if you're interested.)